# Values disappearing from managed object when passed to another view controller

Tags: iphone, core-data

I've got a somewhat complex app using core-data, that is working well except for one instance where data seems to disappear.

I've got a managed object class, pitLayer, with 10 attributes(strings and numbers), a view controller(viewLayers) that displays all the pitLayer objects that belong to a parent object, and a view controller(editLayer) that can edit(and create) new pit layer objects.

When I create a new pitLayer, then return back to the table view, all of the properties show up properly in the table.  If I go immediately back to editLayer all of the values show up properly.

If i then edit another pitLayer with editLayer I get the the correct values for all of the properties except 2, hardness and botttomHardness(both strings), where I still get the values from the previous pitLayer that was edited.

If i load editLayer for the first time with an existing pitLayer the hardness and bottomHardness return nil, all other values return the previously stored value.

The values are getting stored properly, and they can be fetched in viewLayers and return the correct value, but when they are fetched in editLayer they dont return the correct value.  And it is only 2 of the properties, the other 8 seem to work just fine.

Any suggestions for debugging this?

Here is where they get set:

`- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    if(component == kGrainTypeComponent){
        layer.grainType = [[grainTypeValues objectAtIndex:row] valueForKey:@"code"];
    }else if(component == kSecondGrainTypeComponent){
        layer.secondGrainType = [[grainTypeValues objectAtIndex:row] valueForKey:@"code"];
    } else if(component == kHardnessComponent){
        layer.hardness = [[hardnessValues objectAtIndex:row] valueForKey:@"code"];
    } else if(component == kSecondHardnessComponent){
        layer.bottomHardness = [[hardnessValues objectAtIndex:row] valueForKey:@"code"];
    }
    [self checkSavable];
}`

And here is where they fail to get retrieved later:

```
-(void)resetDefaults{
if(edit == YES && layer != nil){//Edit an existing layer
    if(layer.comments)
        comments.text = layer.comments;
    else
        comments.text = @"";
    if(layer.thickness){
        thicknessSlider.value = [layer.thickness floatValue];
        [self thicknessChanged];
    }
    if(layer.grainSize){
        grainSizeSlider.value = [layer.grainSize floatValue];
        [self grainSizeChanged];
    }else{
        grainSizeSlider.value = 0;
        grainSizeLabel.text = @"";
    }
    if(layer.density){
        densitySlider.value = [layer.density floatValue];
        [self densityChanged];
    }else{
        densitySlider.value = 0;
        densityLabel.text = @"";
    }
    NSString *type = layer.grainType;
    NSString *secondType = layer.secondGrainType;
    NSString *hardness = nil;
    hardness = layer.hardness;
    NSString *bottomHardness = nil;
    bottomHardness = layer.bottomHardness;
    NSString *lwc = layer.liquidWaterContent;
    NSUInteger typeIndex = 0;
    NSUInteger secondTypeIndex = 0;
    NSUInteger hardnessIndex = 0;
    NSUInteger bottomHardnessIndex = 0;
    NSLog(@"type:%@, hardness: %@, bottom hardness: %@", type, hardness, bottomHardness);
    if(type){
        for(int i = 0; i < [grainTypeValues count]; i++){
            if([[[grainTypeValues objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"code"]  isEqualToString: type]){
                typeIndex = i;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    [picker selectRow:typeIndex inComponent:kGrainTypeComponent animated:NO];
    if(secondType){
        for(int i = 0; i < [grainTypeValues count]; i++){
            if([[[grainTypeValues objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"code"] isEqualToString:secondType]){
                secondTypeIndex = i;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    [picker selectRow:secondTypeIndex inComponent:kSecondGrainTypeComponent animated:NO];
    if(hardness){
        for(int i = 0; i < [hardnessValues count]; i++){
            if([[[hardnessValues objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"code"] isEqualToString:hardness]){
                hardnessIndex = i;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    [picker selectRow:hardnessIndex inComponent:kHardnessComponent animated:NO];
    if(bottomHardness){
        for(int i = 0; i < [hardnessValues count]; i++){
            if([[[hardnessValues objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"code"] isEqualToString:bottomHardness]){
                bottomHardnessIndex = i;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if(secondHardness)
        [picker selectRow:bottomHardnessIndex inComponent:kSecondHardnessComponent animated:NO];
    if(lwc){
        for(int i = 0; i < [lwcValues count]; i++){
            if([[[lwcValues objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"code"] isEqualToString:lwc]){
                lwcSlider.value = [[[lwcValues objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"value"] floatValue];
                lwcLabel.text = [[lwcValues objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"name"];
                break;
            }
        }
    }else{
        lwcSlider.value = 0;
        lwcLabel.text = @"";
    }
    if(layer.formationDate){
        datePicker.date = layer.formationDate;
        [self dateChanged];
    }else{
        formationDate.text = @"";
        datePicker.date = [NSDate date];
    }

}else{//create a new layer
    comments.text = @"";
    thicknessSlider.value = 0;
    thicknessLabel.text = @"0.0";
    grainSizeSlider.value = 0;
    grainSizeLabel.text = @"";
    densityLabel.text = @"";
    densitySlider.value = 0;
    lwcLabel.text = @"";
    lwcSlider.value = 0;
    formationDate.text = @"";
    datePicker.date = [NSDate date];
    [picker selectRow:0 inComponent:kGrainTypeComponent animated:NO];
    [picker selectRow:0 inComponent:kSecondGrainTypeComponent animated:NO];     
    [picker selectRow:0 inComponent:kHardnessComponent animated:NO];
    if(secondHardness)
        [picker selectRow:0 inComponent:kSecondHardnessComponent animated:NO];
}
thicknessUnitLabel.text = layer.parentPit.depthUnit;
locationUnitLabel.text = layer.parentPit.depthUnit;
densityUnitLabel.text = layer.parentPit.densityUnit;
if([layer.parentPit.densityUnit isEqualToString:@"kg/m3"]){
    densitySlider.maximumValue = 1000;
    densitySliderDecimalCutoff = 0;
}else{
    densitySlider.maximumValue = 100;
    densitySliderDecimalCutoff = 20;
}
topLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1.1F", [[layer topLocation] floatValue]];
bottomLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1.1F", [[layer bottomLocation] floatValue]];
```

}

Comment: Add the code for editLayer - it sounds like something is going wrong in there :)

Answer (score 0):

> The values are getting stored properly, and they can be fetched in
>   viewLayers and return the correct value...

That indicates that the values are getting into the managed object and are being saved to the persistent store.

> ...but when they are fetched in editLayer they dont return the correct
>   value.

Really the only explanation for this is that you are connection the UI elements to the wrong managed object, the wrong attribute or to a nil object.

Debugging that would require seeing the code.